# Importing locally created package in python installed from Pipfile not detected

Tags: python

I created a package folder parallel to my apps folder, where my packages folder will have shared/reusable code that'll be used across different apps and probably published, but before then i need to test it and use it locally.

This is my Pipfile for my mobile folder:

```
[packages]
pronto_auth = {editable = true, path = "../../packages/auth"}
pronto_apis = {editable = true, path = "../../packages/apis"}
flet = "*"
```

Not sure why by my lock file looks like this when i've imported with "_" and not "-"

```
"pronto-apis": {
    "editable": true,
    "path": "../../packages/apis"
},
"pronto-auth": {
    "editable": true,
    "path": "../../packages/auth"
},
```

Yes, it does install sucessfully.

the pronto_auth and apis folder get installed by i can't seem to import it. I get the following error:

`Import "pronto_apis.apis.main.src.main" could not be resolved`

This is how I'm trying to import:

`from pronto_apis.apis.main.src.main import add_two_numbers`

I don't wnat to import like this:

`from packages.apis.main.src.main import add_two_numbers`

because the defeats the purpose of a package like import.

This is my folder structure and import looks like:

[image]

my setup file for both the api and auth looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='pronto_apis',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    description='A brief description of your package',
    install_requires=[],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of learning about Python packaging finally got it working.

1. Updated my setup:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='pronto-apis',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    description='A brief description of your package',
    install_requires=[],
)
```

2. Exported my functions in the init file:

```
from .main import add_two_numbers
```

3. Run the following command to bundle my package:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

This is the step i guess i forgot, I thought I can import a folder but this makes more sense as it generates the bundles

4. Update the package to the bundled package:

```
pronto-apis = {editable = true, path = "../../packages/apis/dist/pronto-apis-0.0.1.tar.gz"}
pronto-auth = {editable = true, path = "../../packages/auth/dist/pronto-auth-0.0.1.tar.gz"}
```

5. Run pipenv install again and import like so:

```
from pronto_auth import add_two_numbers
```